# Proof that if $a,b \in G$ and $a^4b = ba$ and $a^3 = e$ then $ab = ba$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification

I tried to prove one of the examples in my Abstract Algebra book that stated:

> Prove that if $a,b \in G$ and $a^4b = ba$ and $a^3 = e$ then $ab = ba$

I went about just saying that $a^4b = ba \iff a^3(ab) = ba \iff e(ab) = ba$ and the result follows.

However, the book takes a longer route and proves it this way:

> $a^4b = ba \implies b = a^6b = a^2ba \implies ab = a^3ba = ba$

Are both of our proofs valid and equivalent or am I missing something?

Thanks

Comment: Both proofs are valid. Yours is better.

Comment: I'm with anon on this one!

Comment: To be generous to a terrible book proof, perhaps they were trying to do something analagous to the proofs involved with commuting higher powers of $a$ past $b$ - e.g., $a^3b=ba^3$ and $a^7=e$ implies $ab=ba$, as seen [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/206263/) ...

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Yeah, I was also amazed at the complexity of that. But I didn't see any segway into a proof of the property that you described.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to me both proofs are fine.  Mine is a lot like yours:

$a^4b = ba \Rightarrow a^3b = a^{-1}ba; \tag{1}$

$a^3b = a^{-1}ba \; \text{and} \; a^3 = e \Rightarrow b = a^{-1}ba; \tag{2}$

$b = a^{-1}ba \Rightarrow ab = ba. \tag{3}$

***QED!!!***

Comment: There is no point to moving one of the $a$s to the right side only to pull it back again.

Comment: @SalmonKiller:  ha! thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Another way of going around this proof: $$ab = aeb = aa^3b = a^4b = ba$$

Comment: Which is essentially the same as the one you made, now that I think about it.